# TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined on Node.Js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do a simple form submission with Node.js and Express, it's my first time working with this technologies and to be honest I'm stuck.

I got 3 javascript scripts and 1 html page. One of the script is Index.js, where I'm running the server with node.js and express, other is to verify the input on the html and an Ajax call with XMLHttpRequest object if all the data is correct, and the last one is the one who handle the HTTP request and saves the input data on a .json file.

At this moment I'm yet not saving the input data in the .json file.

The problem I'm facing is I'm getting the next error: 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined**

I don't know how to solve it but I know the error is in the script which manage the HTTP request to save it on the json file.

This is the code which trows error:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('querystring');


class SignUp {

  collect(req, res) {
    collectReqData(req, res => {
      console.log(res);
    });

    function collectReqData(request, callback) {
      const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
      const DATA_FORM = 'multipart/form-data';

      if(contentType === DATA_FORM) {

        let body = '';

        request.on('data', chunk => {
          body += chunk.toString();
        });

        request.on('end', () => {
          callback(parse(body));
        });

      }
      else{
        callback(null);
      }
    }

  }

}

var newRequest = new SignUp();

newRequest.collect();

module.exports = SignUp;
```

Next the Ajax call on the verification script:

```
    let formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', './signUp.js');
    request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

And then Index.js file:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html')); 
});

app.get('/submit.js', (req, res) => {
  let k = fs.readFileSync('./submit.js', 'utf8');
  res.send(k);
});

app.post('/signUp.js', (req, res) => {
  let signUp = require('./signUp');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

Please if someone could help me and explain what am I doing wrong I'll be really thankful, and I'll also appreciate any suggestions on my code because I'm new which this technology and it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your `collect` function as `collect(req, res) {` (a function taking two arguments) but at the bottom of your file you call `newRequest.collect();` (passing zero arguments).

The collect function attempts to access `req.headers`, but you didn't pass a request, so it's undefined. Hence the error: "Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined".

It looks like you're trying to call the `collect` function with the request and response from your `app.post('/signUp.js'` route. In that case, you simply need to call `collect` there instead of in the file, so that you can pass the request and response:

```
app.post('/signUp.js', (req, res) => {
  let signUp = require('./signUp');
  signUp.collect(req, res);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Ensure you remove the faulty line from `signUp.js` and export a usable class instance, not the class:

```
//bottom of signUp.js
module.exports = new SignUp();
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help, I'm trying what you are saying but I have no clue on how to call ```newRequest.collect()``` with the request. How can I do it? because if I delete this line I'm getting null as the response

Comment: @FacuCarbonel Don't call `newRequest.collect()`. You don't need to call `.collect()` in the same file as it's declared, because you're exporting it. You need to call `.collect()` from somewhere where you have valid `req, res` request and response objects. This is only in your `index.js` file. That means you need to call `.collect()` on the `signUp` variable, which contains your `SignUp` class with that function.

Comment: Thank you very much! that solved my problem. I'm really glad that you could help me.

Comment: how can "SignUp" class be instantiated when it doesn't use the "this" keyword? i thought in javascript a constructor has to use the "this" keyword to be used as a constructor?

Comment: @vikrant There's no rule like that. Any function or class can be instantiated in js.